# Can I combine these statements?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Can I combine these two statements, or simplify them together...?

```
<%if session("EnrolledInGoGreen") = "T" then %>
    <a href='/ecm/index.aspx'>My Communications</a> 
<%end if%>

<%if session("memGroup") = "xxxxxx"  then %> 
    <a> href='https://outlook.example.com'>Company Email</a> 
<%end if%>
```

Comment: What type of combination or simplification are you looking for?  It's pretty straightfoward code, are these two things supposed to be related on some way?  If not, then what's the problem with the code?

Comment: That may be the answer to my question...I was thinking for simplification purposes, and maintenance, I could just combine them into one statement... but above may be the easiest solution... that was my question I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are evaluating two different things.  If EnrolledInGoGreen and memGroup are truly two different and independent things, then they should be evaluated separately.  No need to combine them, it would not simplify anything, it would actually complicate it because you are putting two different concepts into a single statement.